# Form element is lower than expected. Not sure why

Tags: css

I'm working on theming a drupal site (http://dev.thompsonsurgical.com/), and I can't figure out the positioning of the search items in the top-right. I put a container with a 1px border around the elements in question, and to help illustrate the issue. I can't figure out what is making the input field drop down by about 5px. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should at least give us the relevant CSS. I'd also suggest pasting the piece of HTML in the `header-top` `div`.

Comment: My apologies. I'm new here, and I wasn't sure which CSS was relevent, (and there's a lot of it) so I just gave the link to the page. I'll include the code next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this does it :

```
#edit-search-block-form--2 {
border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
height: 18px;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: top; // modified
}
```

Comment: This solution actually turned out to make more sense and was much cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just played around with your css in firebug and it looks like this is the culprit:

```
.container-inline div, .container-inline label { display:inline }
```

If I get rid of that and add `float:left` it goes to the top. Because of other html elements it is on the right. Try playing around with that and you'll get it to work

Comment: That was it! I gotta run, but I'll tweak it some more tomorrow. Thanks so much!

Comment: You should not "play around", try to understand CSS instead =p

Comment: Thats just how I learned. Played around and then worked to understand why it was happening because I knew what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your `<label>` tag is hidden or wrapping your input, when I viewed it in Chrome's Inspector the label was pushing down the content, you can try relatively positioning the input and setting a negative `top` property

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the baseline default vertical-align which let some space below images. So the `<input />` is just aligned with links.

Add `vertical-align:middle;` for `<img />` and `<input />` elements.